# how to calculate height and width for custom scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

i want to create a small custom scrollbar plugin for my project. Things i made :

1. created two div for horizontal and vertical scrollbar with `position : absolute`
2. added `top : 0` to vertical div (scrollbar) and added `left : 0` to horizontal div (scrollbar)

Now how to add the height for vertical div and width for horizontal div ?

For example, i have a div called container with height 300px and width 500px and inside that, another div with height 376px and width 1600px.

How will i calculate the height for vertical div (scrollbar) and width for horizontal div (scrollbar)?   Here is the [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/n1PxoWXaQdy0yvlB55wq?p=preview)

Comment: For better understanding, Please provide a **working demo** (*code snippet,jsfiddle ...*)

Comment: try this https://css-tricks.com/examples/WebKitScrollbars/

Comment: @KishoreSahas : link added. Refer that. I added static value for custom scroll.  In your link, they are customizing the scrollbar, but i want to create my own scrollbar

Comment: try this http://plnkr.co/edit/LYihZ8XJJvMTT09FApIM?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var all = document.getElementById('everything'), //contain all (area,content,scroll)
    elem = document.getElementById('scroll-area'), //area
    track = all.children[1], //scroll tracker
    thumb = track.children[0],//scroll thumb (handle)
    height = parseInt(elem.offsetHeight, 10), //get the area height
    cntHeight = parseInt(elem.children[0].clientHeight, 10), //get content height
    trcHeight = parseInt(track.offsetHeight, 10), //get tracker height
    mean = 50, // For multiplier (go faster or slower)
    current = 0;

thumb.style.height = Math.round(height / cntHeight * trcHeight) + 'px'; // Set the scrollbar thumb hight (area height / (content height * tracker height)

var doScroll = function (e) {
    // cross-browser wheel delta
    e = window.event || e;
    var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));

    var scrolltop = elem.scrollTop;

    // scrollTop property takes positive values when you scroll down and our delta variable behaves otherwise, so the equation will be:
    elem.scrollTop = scrolltop - delta * mean;

    // set top position for the scrollbar thumb
    thumb.style.top = (elem.scrollTop / cntHeight * trcHeight) + 'px';

    e.preventDefault();
};

if (elem.addEventListener) {
    elem.addEventListener("mousewheel", doScroll, false);
    elem.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", doScroll, false);
} else {
    elem.attachEvent("onmousewheel", doScroll);
}
```

```css
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
body {
    background-color:white;
    padding:10px;
    font:normal normal 16px/1.4 Times, Serif;
    color:black;
}
#everything {
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    height: 300px;
}
#scroll-area {
    width:250px;
    height:300px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#scroll-area .scroll-content {
    padding: 0px;
    border-bottom:1px solid red;
    /* just for test */
}
.scrollbar-track {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0px;
    width:10px;
    background-color: none;
}
.scrollbar-thumb {
    cursor:pointer;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:10px;
    /*height:30px;*/
    background-color:#88f;
}
p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="everything">
    <div id="scroll-area">
        <div class="scroll-content">
            
             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.</p>
                <p><strong>The End!</strong>
                </p>
            
             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.</p>
                <p><strong>The End!</strong>
                </p>
            
        </div>
    </div>
<span class="scrollbar-track"><span class="scrollbar-thumb"></span></span>
</div>
```

Demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/uBLfzfjYJE8RSIOqz0Cl?p=preview

Comment: oh..you are the man.:)  But can you explain it briefly about your code

Comment: Sure, you can see this is the part of calculating the height `thumb.style.height = Math.round(height / cntHeight * trcHeight) + 'px';`

Comment: I will add more comments for your better understanding

Comment: i have one doubt. For iphone and ipad, instead of mousewheel, if we use touchmove, will it work?

Comment: I have not tried it with my code, but technically it should work.

Comment: How to calculate horizontal scrollbar width?